# how to add value in xml file by using sed

Tags: xml, sed

i have xml file here as shown in below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Application xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="fabric:/mytype" xmlns="http://we.xyti.com/2011/01/gone">  <Parameters>
<Parameter Name="mytype" Value="-1" />
<Parameter Name="new1" Value="" />
<Parameter Name="new2" Value="" />
<Parameter Name="new3" Value="" />
<Parameter Name="new4" Value="" /> </Parameters></Application></Application>`
```

In the above xml i need to add value in each line eg:- instead "" have to put value as test, different for each `Name` attribute. E.g.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Application xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="fabric:/mytype" xmlns="http://we.xyti.com/2011/01/gone">  <Parameters>
<Parameter Name="mytype" Value="-1" />
<Parameter Name="new1" Value="test1" />
<Parameter Name="new2" Value="test2" />
<Parameter Name="new3" Value="test3" />
<Parameter Name="new4" Value="test4" /> </Parameters></Application></Application>
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  it didnt slve my qauestion coz <Parameter Name="new1" Value=""/> i need add value in "" on each line :) -thank you for reply

Comment: Yes, so what is the problem with `sed -E 's/(enable-welcome-root=")"/\1NEWVALUE"/' file`? The solution is there, you just need to remove `[^"]+` that requires a value to be present (and will be replaced). Add `g` at the end to replace multiple occurrences : `sed -E 's/(enable-welcome-root=")"/\1NEWVALUE"/g' file`

Comment: i tried :) and in mycase i need added  where "" need to add "test"
<Parameter Name="new1" Value="" />
<Parameter Name="new2" Value="" />
<Parameter Name="new3" Value="" />
<Parameter Name="new4" Value=""/> @WiktorStribiżew  all will be diffenrt value

Comment: So replace `NEWVALUE` with `test` in my above code.

Comment: sed -e 's/(Value=")"/\test"/g' "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\test\Cloud.xml"
getting error -e expression #1, char 21: Unknown option to `s :(

Comment: Copy/paste: `sed -E 's/( Value=")"/\1test"/g' file > newfile`. Are you on Windows? Make sure ``\`` do not need to double the ``\``s in your path, or just use single quotes, `'C:\Users\user1\Desktop\test\Cloud.xml'`

Comment: invalid option -- E

Comment: If `-E` does not work, try `-r`. If `-r` does not work, use `sed 's/\( Value="\)"/\1test"/g' 'C:\Users\user1\Desktop\test\Cloud.xml' > 'C:\Users\user1\Desktop\test\Cloud_out.xml'`

Comment: : -e expression #1, char 24: Unknown option to `s'
sorry for long discussion .. and thank you so much so helping .. plz help me out in slovein this am using this command 
"C:\Users\bizruntime\Desktop\test\sed.exe" -e "s/\( Value="\)"/\1test"/g" "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\test\Cloud.xml" > "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\test\Cloud_out.xml"

Comment: [Look here](http://rextester.com/XFKS15590), you keep using `-e`, don't.

Comment: Aswme thank you so much :)  but last i need add different different value for  new 1 and new2 and new3 line on value="'

Comment: That  is really simple, see http://rextester.com/UHXI47492

Comment: Yes sloved .. thank you so much mate :) @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: **Do not use regex to parse XML.**   It will fail to omit commented-out XML properly.  It will fail in a myriad of ways.  Just because you can hack a regex for a simple case doesn't mean you ought to.   Commenters: Recommend real, robust solutions such as those based upon XML parsers or XPath be used instead.  It's the responsible thing to do.  See @Cyrus's answer below for one robust way to solve OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

With this xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Application xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://we.xyti.com/2011/01/gone" Name="fabric:/mytype">
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="mytype" Value="-1"/>
    <Parameter Name="new1" Value=""/>
    <Parameter Name="new2" Value=""/>
    <Parameter Name="new3" Value=""/>
    <Parameter Name="new4" Value=""/>
  </Parameters>
</Application>
```

and xmlstarlet:

```
xmlstarlet edit -N x="http://we.xyti.com/2011/01/gone" --update '//x:Parameter/@Value' --value "test" file.xml
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Application xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://we.xyti.com/2011/01/gone" Name="fabric:/mytype">
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter Name="mytype" Value="test"/>
    <Parameter Name="new1" Value="test"/>
    <Parameter Name="new2" Value="test"/>
    <Parameter Name="new3" Value="test"/>
    <Parameter Name="new4" Value="test"/>
  </Parameters>
</Application>
```